# Flyway migrations changed by mistake

Tags: flyway

I changed a flyway script for error, and this brought my migrations to an error state (I have 5 script versions, but when I run my app it starts from the 4th, and get an error on 'reaction already exists').
I tried to use clean from flyway cli, but it didn't completely solve the problem... also, when I try pushing my branch to git, CI/CD pipeline will fail for the migration.
Since I'm in development environment, would it be a terrible idea to all delete migration scripts?
Would deleting all scripts allow me to 'start from scratch' in my development environment, or do I need to push the whole project again to avoid issues? (Project is not in production yet, I don't really need flyway migrations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which flyway version you are using, one option is to go to the flyway_schema_history or schema_version table and just locate the row (corresponding to the failed script) and change the success column to true or 1. Then manually run the script (the correct one) against DB.